# Error in USB debugging live testing in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and I install React Native and I want to test using y device (Realme 2).

Using USB debugging, but I am stuck on this same mobile using [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) runs in ADB.
This stucks at this position I await multiple 15m

info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
> File C:\Users\Muhammed Sajid Ali.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
> Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in D:\sajid\AndroidSdk\licenses
> License for package Android SDK Platform 28 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 28 (revision: 6)".
> <======-------> 50% CONFIGURING [15m 0s]
> :app

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

I earlier installed the Android SDK 8, 7.4.4, and 9 versions, but my mobile was 8.1. That’s why
it didn't start and it was downloading SDK 8.1. As I saw in the Android SDK folder, there was a new folder with some files.

Then I downloaded the 8.1 SDK, and it ran perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

I think that was no problem with your compiler behavior, but I can suggest you to **check** if installing the app from USB is permitted in your phone's developer option and try to **trigger** the compiler with pressing return key (or enter) on the command line. That was working on mine.

Comment: walekum assalam, sir using same mobile i am able to run live hello wold app from android studio.

Comment: if you can run that on your AVD then those should work on your real device too